# convert from single site to multisite (network) with existing subdomains

Tags: multisite

We currently use wordpress to manage our website under our main domain.
We also have a few subdomain under which different applications run.

```
www.example.com // our main website, running wordpress
extranet.example.com // a custom-made LAMP application
forum.example.com // another LAMP application
*.example.com // anything can happen in there.
```

We would like to use the Network feature to create subdomains in which each team can have its own communication tool based on wordpress + buddypress.

Question: can i convert our main wordpress installation to Network with subdomain, without removing access to extranet.* and forum.* ? I [read the manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), but it doesn't address the specific case where subdomains already exist and i'm afraid to break things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems possible to me. Most of this is related to server management and not only WordPress, so probably [Server Fault also has interesting info on this](https://serverfault.com/search?q=wildcard+dns).

On the DNS side, you would create a wildcard to the server with WordPress, and define your other subdomains to the servers that host those (some or all of them can be the same as the WordPress server). [Wildcards always have the least priority](https://serverfault.com/questions/128673/where-would-a-wildcard-dns-record-be-prioritized/128724#128724).

For the server side it is useful to know that if a request reaches Apache but it finds no matching `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` in a `<VirtualHost>`, the first virtual host is returned. So you configure the WordPress setup as the first host and the others running on that server after it.